# TradingView - unable to set color for top toolbar

Tags: tradingview-api

I have the following setting overrides for my TV chart:

```
    let chartStyleOverrides = {
      'scalesProperties.bgColor': bgColor,
      'paneProperties.background': bgColor,
      'paneProperties.backgroundType': 'solid',
      'paneProperties.legendProperties.showBackground': false,
    };
```

They change the color of everything except the very top bar (you can see it's white not gray).

How do I change the color of top bar?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I only managed to do this using the custom CSS option, which works like this:

Create a CSS file like `custom.css`, with contents like the following:

```
.theme-dark:root {
    --tv-color-platform-background: #222222;
    --tv-color-pane-background: #222222;
    --tv-color-pane-background-secondary: #222222;
}
```

Then add this option to the list of options when you instantiate the `TradingView` widget:

```
custom_css_url: '../custom.css',
```

In case you use a bundler like webpack, make sure to save the CSS file to your public folder.